# How can I get better speeds for one device in my home without relying on the router's settings?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, macbook

My router is a technicolor TG589vac and doesn't support QoS as far as I know.

I am wondering, is there an app I can use or process I can go through on my macOS Sierra Macbook Pro to be able to increase its wifi speeds while perhaps being detrimental to the speeds of the other devices in my home?

Maybe there is a way to trick the router into thinking my device is more than one, so it supports me twice, thrice etc. as much as all the other solo devices.

I don't really know how routers work to be honest, but I feel like it might be possible to get better prioritisation from my router without having to change anything about the router.

Comment: I am sorry for asking such a crappy question that the reason for downvoting is so obvious it doesn't need explanation

Comment: You could buy a new router or get faster Internet!

Comment: I didn't downvote this, just looked at it for the first time, but the reason is probably because it shows you did little research on your own and seem to lack a basic understanding of WiFi and networking technology in general. Are you looking to speed up your connection between the router and the Macbook, the Macbook to get priority for Internet communications, for other devices to be throttled, or ??? What have you tried to do, anything? I can say that your router is a modem and router that is not designed to do what you want. Are you willing to invest a several hundred in a quality router?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a way to accomplish that using third-party software tools.

The only way software could accomplish something similar to what you're asking for would be by flooding the network from your computer, which might cause issues for the other clients, but would not improve your own.

In order to accomplish what you request, you need a router that supports QoS.

Comment: Because I believed it provided relevant context to explain WHY such a utility would be useless for you, even IF it existed.